How to fix sending e-mails to Gmail in MailKit?
Using MailKit, I want to send a verification code to rescue the password in my application.
I've copied working code that I've previously used:
       private async void RescuePassword(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           string[] nums = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
           if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("No password selected", "No password selected", buttons:                                                         MessageBoxButtons.OK, icon: MessageBoxIcon.Error);
               return;
           }

           rescuePasswordVericationCode = "";
           for (int _ = 0; _ < 4; _++)
           {
               rescuePasswordVericationCode += nums[rnd.Next(0, 10)];
           }
           await Task.Run(() =>
           {
               MimeMessage gmailMessage = new();
               gmailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Safity", "thatonegmail@gmail.com"));
               gmailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Client", textBox2.Text));
               gmailMessage.Subject = "Verification code";

               gmailMessage.Body = new TextPart("plain")
               {
                   Text = $"Your verification code is {verificationCode}"
               };

               using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
               {
                   client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, false);
                   client.Authenticate("thatonegmail@gmail.com", "this isnt real pswd");
                   client.Send(gmailMessage);
                   client.Disconnect(true);
               }
           });
       }

There's an error:

MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpCommandException: „5.5.2 Syntax error, cannot decode response. For more information, go to https://support.google.com/a/answer/3221692 and review RFC 5321 specifications. a640c23a62f3a-a99efe3caebsm81376566b.16 - gsmtp”

I don't know why It's not working this time.

Bit hard to tell what might be happening with the info you gave. A few pointers and things to try

MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.StartTls instead of false in the Connect call
Are you aware of Less secure apps & your Google Account


Starting on September 30, 2024, less secure apps, third-party apps, or devices that have you sign in with only your username and password will no longer be supported for Google Workspace accounts.


Did you try (or are already using) an App password

Sign in with app passwords
See also related question How to use MailKit with Google after May 30, 2022?


Current best practice would be to use OAuth2

MailKit Docus: Using OAuth2 With GMail (IMAP, POP3 or SMTP)



